# JQuery video upload returning success message but error event is firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wistia

I have API to upload video in wistia server. I using Ajax jquery to post video to server, video getting uploaded to server and success message is coming. But the problem is error event is getting fired nothing coming in success event.

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="File1" type="file" />
    <input id="Submit1" type="button" value="save video" onclick="SaveFile();" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
function SaveFile() {
        alert('111111');           
        var pData = new FormData();
        var files = $("#File1").get(0).files;
        pData.append("project_id", "*******");           
        pData.append("file", files[0]);           
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://upload.wistia.com/?access_token=***************',
            type: 'POST',
            data: pData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'multipart/form-data',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {                   
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (e) {                    
                alert(JSON.stringify(e));
                alert('error');                    
            }
        }).done(function () {
            alert('Done');
        });
```

Response:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"id\":16549615,\"name\":\"VID-20151103-WA0000.mp4\",\"type\":\"Video\",\"created\":\"2015-11-03T10:28:25+00:00\",\"updated\":\"2015-11-03T10:28:25+00:00\",\"duration\":112.046,\"hashed_id\":\"********\",\"description\":\"\",\"progress\":0.0,\"status\":\"queued\",\"thumbnail\":{\"url\":\"https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/5b83b5db28f38876963829e0de30039d52eb80bc.jpg?image_crop_resized=100x60&video_still_time=56\",\"width\":100,\"height\":60},\"account_id\":******}","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

This is coming in error event.

Comment: ... and the error is...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  No error its showing success message in error event.

Comment: what's the HTTP status of the response?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of the console to see the actual response?

Comment: check i have posted the response which i am getting in error event.